¿Cómo puedo hacer que el código se vuelva a ejecutar dada cierta condición?
La idea es crear un script que organice los archivos por formato, en carpetas específicas dentro de descargas como: img, videos, audios, y que si estas no existen las añada.
# -- La idea es crear un script que organize los archivos por formato en carpetas especificas dentro de descargas como Imagenes, Videos, Musica y que si estas no existen las añada
import os
import magic
from shutil import move as mover_archivo
from colorama import init, Fore, Style, Back
init();

### --- listas de formatos disponibles --- ###
lista_formatos_videos = ["video/mov", "video/mp4", "video/avi", "video/wmv", "video/flv"]
lista_formatos_imagenes = ["image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/bmp", "image/gif", "image/tiff", "image/heif", "image/raw", "image/psd", "image/svg", "image/webp", "image/eps", "image/"]
lista_formatos_audios = ["audio/x-wav", "audio/mpeg"]

### --- Funcion para la creacion de las carpetas --- ###
def crear_carpeta(arg_directory):
    directory = arg_directory

    parent_dir = "C://Users//rdev//Downloads"

    path = os.path.join(parent_dir, directory)

    os.mkdir(path)
    print(Fore.CYAN + "Directorio %s creado" %directory)
    print("-------------------------------------------------")

### --- Funcion simple que mueve los archivos --- ###
print("")
print(Fore.LIGHTGREEN_EX + "")
print("-------------------------------------------------")
### --- Verificacion de acceso a las carpetas --- ###
pathSec_1 = os.access("C://Users//rdev//Downloads//Videos", os.F_OK)
if pathSec_1 == True:
    print(Fore.LIGHTGREEN_EX + "La carpeta Videos: ", pathSec_1)
else:
    print(Fore.LIGHTRED_EX + "La carpeta Videos: ", pathSec_1)
    

pathSec_2 = os.access("C://Users//rdev//Downloads//Musica", os.F_OK)
if pathSec_2 == True:
    print(Fore.LIGHTGREEN_EX + "La carpeta Musica: ", pathSec_2)
else:
    print(Fore.LIGHTRED_EX + "La carpeta Musica: ", pathSec_2)

pathSec_3 = os.access("C://Users//rdev//Downloads//Imagenes", os.F_OK)
if pathSec_3 == True:
    print(Fore.LIGHTGREEN_EX + "La carpeta Imagenes: ", pathSec_3)
else:
    print(Fore.LIGHTRED_EX + "La carpeta Imagenes: ", pathSec_3)
print(Fore.LIGHTGREEN_EX + "-------------------------------------------------")
### --- Creacion de las carpetas utilizando la funcion crear_carpetas() --- ###
if pathSec_1 == False:
    crear_carpeta("Videos")

if pathSec_2 == False:
    crear_carpeta("Musica")

if pathSec_3 == False:
    crear_carpeta("Imagenes")

### --- Modificar el directorio actual neccesario por culpa de un error --- ###
os.chdir('C://Users//rdev//Downloads')

### --- Verifica los archivos existentes en descargas con el listdir
### --- isfile sirve para que los directorios no se revisen y no aparescan
### --- los directorios generan un error --- ###
lista = list(filter(os.path.isfile, os.listdir()))
print("")
print(Fore.LIGHTMAGENTA_EX + "Los Archivos en la carpeta descargas son los siguientes")
print("---------------------------------------------------------------------------")
lista2 = lista
for z in lista2:
    print(Fore.LIGHTYELLOW_EX + z)
print(Style.RESET_ALL)
#for xx in lista:
#    dd = magic.from_file("C://Users//rdev//Downloads//Timeline 1.mp4", mime = True)
#    print(dd)

### --- Iterar la lista con los archivos para poder ir uno por uno revisandolo con
### --- la libreria magic que revisa la cabezera de los archivos para saber que formato son --- ###
for x in lista:

### --- Estas dos lineas de codigo verifican el formato de cada archivo el mime resume el formato --- ###
    valor_actual_lista = x
    formato_archivo = magic.from_file(valor_actual_lista , mime = True)

### --- El argumento formato utiliza las listas creadas al inicio del codigo linea 8 y 9
### --- el argumento path_carpeta es utilizado por mover_archivos()
### --- como argumento para mover los archivos con shutil.move arg1 = nombre de archivo
### --- arg2 = carpeta a la cual moverlo tambien se utiliza para imprimir
### --- a cual carpeta se movio en consola --- ###
    def mover_archivos_formato(formato, path_carpeta):
        for y in formato:
            Carpeta = path_carpeta
            if y == formato_archivo:
                mover_archivo(valor_actual_lista, path_carpeta)
                print("")
                print(Fore.LIGHTGREEN_EX + "Se a movido con exito: %s" % valor_actual_lista, "a la carpeta", Carpeta)
    
### --- Utilizasion de la funcion para mover los archivos a partir de su formato a su carpeta correspondiente --- ###
    mover_archivos_formato(lista_formatos_videos, "Videos")
    mover_archivos_formato(lista_formatos_imagenes, "Imagenes")
    mover_archivos_formato(lista_formatos_audios, "Musica")

def EER():
    while True:
        print(Fore.LIGHTMAGENTA_EX + "")
        print("quieres volver a ordenar los archivos")
        Condition = input("---- [ Y ] or [ N ] ----: ")
        if Condition == "Y":
            pass
        elif Condition == "y":
            pass
        else:
            quit()

EER()

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que en el momento en que se ejecute el def eer(): el programa al poner "y" vuelva a ejecutarse el código y reorganice todo otra vez?

Uyyy, muy bien por ti y tu motivación, pero lamentablemente [so] no es para realizar consultorías, sino para corregir problemas de código. Tu pregunta incluso cae en una categiría de "Basada en Opiniones", por lo que es seguro que termine cerrada. Hasta lo que se, tu código está bien ordenado, y bien comentado para lo que tu necesitas saber. Recomiendo que el nombre de las variables las manejes mas detallado y en el mismo lenguaje. Algunas se llaman formato o lista_formato_videos, pero luego tienes pathSecc_1, y 2, y 3... luego tambien tienes la variable z, entonces eso puede mejorar.

Veo que lo único que hace mover_archivos es llamar a shutil.move, asi que si quieres ahorrarte un par de lineas puedes hacer from shutil import move as mover_archivos y no necesitarías definir la función por tu cuenta.

Te recomendaría eliminar def Programa(), dejando el resto del código a primer nivel. Así te queda más claro el código. Las funciones dentro de funciones suelen usarse para simplificar el código de la función principal cuando una cierta operación se repite dentro de esa función principal, pero no fuera.

Hola Catriel, prueba con: def EER():
while True:
print( "quieres volver a ordenar los archivos" )
Condition = input("---- [ Y ] or [ N ] ----: ")
if Condition == "Y":
formato = input( "Introduce el formato" )
carpeta =  input( "Introduce la carpeta" )
mover_archivos_formato( formato, carpeta )
else:
quit()  # break te saca del while y return de la función.

@MarcePuente Gracias el bucle funciono pero no mueve  nada se me ocurrio que puede ser por que no sabe que archivos hay con ese formato

No soy muy bueno con Python, pero me parece que el problema está en el for x in lista: y su contenido, en principio, yo sacaría el método mover_archivos_formato afuera del for, todo el for, lo pondría en otro método y llamaría a este desde EER, PD: si es tu primer programa... vas a llegar lejos!!!.

@MarcePuente Gracias por la ayuda en el momento lo intente pero vi un problema y lo intente de otra forma logre hacerlo pero ahora me doy cuenta de una forma a partir de lo que pusiste que creo serviria gracias intentare volver a crear el mismo programa pero con mejor codigo disculpe las molestias

Maestro, no es ninguna molestia, es un placer colaborar con usted!!.
